# Referencing Excel Cells in VBA

Tags: vba

My main problem is assigning a variable an manipulating it in VBA.

I know that this code works, but I'm not sure if it this is a proper way to assign a variable in VBA like I have with currentcell = Cells(i, 1).Value

```
Sub C()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 4
currentcell = Cells(i, 1).Value
MsgBox currentcell
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you can try google that first. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/reference-cells-and-ranges

Comment: This is too broad. Stack Overflow isn't designed to duplicate material found in almost any tutorial. Having said that, Stack Overflow is a good resource if and when you encounter specific difficulties while learning VBA. If you have a good programming background, you should find VBA very easy to pick up. In just a few hours you should be able to learn a usable subset.

Comment: Please see my edits John, thank you.

Comment: @JohnColeman except a lot of VBA tutorials are terrible learning material and teach the wrong things. Documentation.SO had everything in one place, and now it's gone. I'd much rather see proactive, eager-to-learn "best practices" questions like this one than yet-another-duplicate question asking why they're getting run-time error 1004 with their unqualified implicit `ActiveSheet` references all over their code, because that's what they copy/pasted from online tutorials, or adapted from macro-recorder code.

Comment: @newacc2240 see, "tutorials" like this, that mangle *getting a workbook reference*, *getting a worksheet reference*, and *accessing a range from a worksheet* and put everything in one single instruction, without declaring or using a single object variable, are exactly why people write shitty VBA code in the first place, that dereferences the same object 30 times in as many lines.

Comment: FWIW - In response to your comment to me on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46760201/6535336) (now deleted), the correct way to assign the value **back** to the cell would be `Cells(i, 1).Value = regex.Replace(Cells(i, 1), "<Replace>")` or, using this question's code as an example,  `Cells(i, 1).Value = currentcell`.

Answer (score 1):

What the macro recorder and a lot of tutorials won't tell you, is that these calls are implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`, which is obviously implicitly in the `ActiveWorkbook`. When all you ever have to deal with is a single worksheet, it's probably fine, but reality is that it's never the case, and code written with implicit references to the `ActiveSheet` is incredibly frail, bug-prone, and the underlying cause behind way too many Stack Overflow questions tagged with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba):

- `Cells`
- `Range`
- `Name`
- `Rows`
- `Columns`

Whenever you use any of those, you're making calls against some global-scope `Property Get` accessor that "conveniently" fetches the `ActiveSheet` reference for you:

> [image: Rubberduck toolbar showing "Excel._Global.Cells (property get accessor:Range)"]
>
> <sub>Screenshot of [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com)'s toolbar, showing the declaration site of the selected code. **Disclaimer**: I manage that open-source VBIDE add-in project.</sub>

So yes, this "works", but what you'll want is to work off an *explicit* `Worksheet` object reference instead. There are **many** ways to get a `Worksheet` object reference, but the best one is to not care about where the worksheet is coming from, and take it as a parameter:

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    Dim currentCell As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 4
        currentcell = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        'in-cell error values can't be converted to a string:
        If Not IsError(currentCell) Then MsgBox currentcell
    Next i
End Sub
```

This takes the responsibility of knowing exactly what worksheet to work with away from the procedure, and gives it to the calling code, which can look like this:

```
DoSomething Sheet1 'uses the sheet's CodeName property
```

Or this:

```
DoSomething ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Period" & n)
```

Or whatever. There are plenty of ways, each with their own gotchas - often you'll see something like this:

```
DoSomething Sheets("Sheet1") 'where "Sheet1" is in ThisWorkbook
```

Except `Sheets` implicitly refers to the `ActiveWorkbook` *which may or may not be `ThisWorkbook`*, and the `Sheets` collection could return a `Chart` object, which isn't a `Worksheet`. Also if `"Sheet1"` is in `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook with the code that's running), then referring to a worksheet by name means your code breaks as soon as the user renames the tab for that sheet.

The most robust way to refer to a worksheet that exists at compile/design-time, is by its `CodeName`. Select the sheet in the *Project Explorer* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), then bring up the *Properties* toolwindow (<kbd>F4</kbd>), and set its `CodeName` by changing the `(Name)` property to whatever you need: VBA defines a global-scope global object variable by that name, so you can call it `MyAwesomeReport` and then refer to it as such in code:

```
DoSomething MyAwesomeReport
```

And that code will not break if the user changes the worksheet's "name".

---

Your code (however small that snippet might be) has other issues, notably it's using undeclared variables, which means you're not using `Option Explicit`, which is another thing that will end up biting you in the rear end and come to Stack Overflow with an embarrassing question that boils down to a typo - because without `Option Explicit` specified at the top of every module, VBA will happily compile a typo, making your code behave strangely instead of simply not compiling. These bugs can be excruciatingly hard to find, and they're ridiculously easy to prevent:

> Use. Option. Explicit. Always.

Comment: An occasional too-broad question isn't a bad thing when it generates answers like this. +1